# Object prototype may only be an Object or null at Function.create (native) in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

hi friend i am trying node.js which is much in demand now a days, so thought to get some hands on this amazing js,
so 1stly, i want to install mysql for to create databse for my app,
i used following command to install mysql
`$ npm install mysql`

sql1.js code

```
var mysql      = require('mysql'); 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution); });

connection.end();
```

but when i run my sql1.js which contains the sql code
throws error

```
pitambar@pitambar-TravelMate-4740:~/node-example/hands-on-node.js$
node sql1.js

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^ TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null
    at Function.create (native)
    at Object.inherits (util.js:425:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pitambar/.node_libraries/.npm/readable-stream/1.1.10/package/lib/_stream_readable.js:55:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pitambar/.node_libraries/.npm/readable-stream/1.1.10/package/readable.js:1:90)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26) pitambar@pitambar-TravelMate-4740:~/node-example/hands-on-node.js$
```

what to do in such case, i m new to node
any help will be appreciated ,thank you

Comment: I have the same issue too